# after changing compiz configs - the panels disappeared

Tags: 11.04, compiz

after changing compiz configs - the panels disappeared

I just see my files on the desktop,
Problem I cant open settings to reset the compiz settings or what ever happend.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can reset your Unity configuration with `unity --reset` (via [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration))

Comment: thx for the quick help

Comment: It does seem that many compiz settings can conflict with unity. I have had to reset mine several times over the last few days of playing with CCSM.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the contents of `unity --help`, running `unity --reset` will clear any custom settings you use in the unity plugin.

When my panel disappears, I instead run `unity --replace`

Comment: I was doing this so often while tweaking CCSM that I set it to a keyboard shortcut, haha

Answer (score 0):

1. create a launcher for terminal, with the command gnome-terminal
2. then Open compiz in terminal with the command ccsm,
3. go to preferences then click the Reset to Defaults

this work fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unity's `--reset` switch is deprecated. To reset Unity's settings run the following 2 commands:

(This should only apply to **13.04** and **13.10**, I'm not sure about older versions)

1. Install dconf if you don't have it: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Reset compiz settings: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` (This is not a path on your disk, but it just identifies compiz-specific settings)
3. Restart Unity: `setsid unity`
4. Never use compiz again (You can obviously skip this step)